# Reference a React Element before its declared in JSX

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am implementing [react-native-zss-rich-text-editor](https://github.com/wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor) in my project and am having a issue where the `RichTextToolbar` needs a function that returns a ref to a `RichTextEditor` component.

If I order the RichTextEditor before the RichTextToolbar it works fine

```
<RichTextEditor
  ref={(r) => this.richtext = r}/>
<RichTextToolbar
    getEditor={() => this.richtext}/>
```

But I would like to first render the `RichTextToolbar` and then the `RichTextEditor` which throws an exception

```
    <RichTextToolbar
        getEditor={() => this.richtext}/>  <-----
    <RichTextEditor
      ref={(r) => this.richtext = r}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<RichTextToolbar
    getEditor={() => this.richtext ? this.richtext : <div/>}/>
<RichTextEditor
  ref={(r) => this.richtext = r}/>
```

This solution is put something compatible with requirements of component `RichTextToolbar` to it. If `div` is not good - replace it with some else.

according to your comment try this:

```
{ this.richtext ?
  <RichTextToolbar
      getEditor={() => this.richtext}/>
  : null
}
<RichTextEditor
  ref={(r) => this.richtext = r}/>
```

Comment: I tried something similar but the componentDidMount function of RichTextToolbar tries to register the RichTextEditor and throws and exception.

Comment: if my solution is good for you please give me vote and answer mark please.

Comment: Just tried that. It still failed on line 69 of the RichTextToolbar https://github.com/wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor/blob/master/src/RichTextToolbar.js. I may have to fork the code and fix it .... was hoping there would be a JSX trick whereby I can reorder the rendering or so.

Comment: That possible another reason. Becouse as you can see the `RichTextToolbar` component is created only after `this.richtext` reach its value. If it failed at line 69 this mean that editor is set at properly time but some another problem with it value or with another data.

Comment: You are correct .. i fixed that and now its on line 67

Comment: If execution reach line 67 - that mean editor reference is not ready at creation time. And that mean that you use some another code but not my second code sample.

Comment: RichTextEditor is only called once in my code and its below the sample code you gave